# How to add icon inside the input field with the placeholder text

Tags: html, css

How do I add an icon as the placeholder text inside an input field?
The icon is placed outside of the input field. I tried moving it using padding and margin, but I can't seem to position it exactly where I want it.

[image]

Comment: use `negative margin` or `absolute` positioning and  [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide code that you are using for this. Also please take a look at how to ask a good question on Stack Overflow here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap4/bootstrap5 you can do easily

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
<div class="container">  
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <div class="input-group-text">
           <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
         </div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="search here" class="form-control" name="search" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Check this

Comment: Clicking on the icon does not focus the input field. This will cause user frustration.

Comment: it depends how you are using it there can be many scenarios let's say if you want some function should run on click icon then your answer is not the right choice because in that case icon should work as button also in most of the cases it is used just for indication to show what that input field really means @JustinTaddei

Comment: To address your first point about interactivity, if clicking the icon should perform some action, it would be better for the icon to focus the input if the input is empty, and take over the inactivity with Javascript when the user has typed something. as for your second point, if the icon is purely for indication, it should absolutely focus the input if it is clicked. Many people expect this behavior (especially an older audience in my experience) and lacking it causes cognitive friction.

Comment: yes that can be easily achieved just by using  focus class inside input field but here question is to show icon inside the input field so functionality we can add as required @JustinTaddei

Answer (score 6):

Your best option is either using CSS Grid or Flexbox to center the icon within a wrapper element.

You can read more about Grid here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

And you can read more about Flexbox here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout

Here is an example using Grid:

```css
body {
  background: #F5F5F6;
}

label {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr / auto 1fr;
  gap: 12px;
  
  
  border: 1px solid #CFD5DB;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fafafa;
  padding: 12px;
  color: #6C757D;
  cursor: text;
}

label:focus-within {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

label>input {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="css-i6dzq1">
    <circle cx="11" cy="11" r="8"></circle>
    <line x1="21" y1="21" x2="16.65" y2="16.65"></line>
  </svg>
  <input placeholder="Enter Hotel name" type="search" />
</label>
```

**A couple of important things to note about this example:**

- I've used a `label` element to wrap the `input`. This gives us the behavior of clicking the icon to focus the input field without needing to use javascript.
- I've used `input[type=search]` because that is more semantically correct for your usage, and will aid users of screen readers in understanding the purpose of the text field.
- I've used the `:focus-within` pseudo-selector to target and style the `label` when its child `input` is focused.
- I've opted to use an `svg` icon but an `img` based icon will work just as well.
- I could've used Flexbox just as easily but I wanted to use the `gap` property on the wrapping `label` instead of setting a margin on the icon or input. `gap` also works with Flexbox the same way it does with Grid except that Safari only supports `gap` on Grid layouts. If you opt for the Flexbox method, use a margin on one of the child elements instead of `gap`.

Answer (score 0):

Place the two inline controls (the `image` and the `input`) into a container (e.g. a Div).

The container must be styled `position:relative`

Style the inline elements as `position:absolute; top:0; left:0`, which will place them one-on-top-of-the-other. Then use `z-index` to decide which element is on top and which is below.

Then a bit of padding, so that the input text is pushed over to the right to make room for the image... and you have it.

*The `border-radius` is not necessary - it only rounds the corners of the image.*

```css
.iwi{
  position:relative;
}

img,input{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;}

input{
  z-index:1;
  font-size:1.3rem;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  padding-left:25px;
}
img{
  z-index:2;
  margin-top:7px;
  margin-left:3px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
::placeholder{
  color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="iwi">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/20/20" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name the kitten" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Add icon library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.input-container {
  display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.icon {
  padding: 10px;
  background: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  min-width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.input-field {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: none;
}

.input-field:focus {
  border: 2px solid dodgerblue;
}

/* Set a style for the submit button */
.btn {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.btn:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php" style="max-width:500px;margin:auto">
  <h2>Register Form</h2>
  <div class="input-container">
    <i class="fa fa-user icon"></i>
    <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="usrnm">
  </div>

  <div class="input-container">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope icon"></i>
    <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email">
  </div>
  
  <div class="input-container">
    <i class="fa fa-key icon"></i>
    <input class="input-field" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="psw">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn">Register</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]